# angular2 how to pass callback method from component into class (typescript file)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class called data.ts. In that i have a method which is called from various components. This method subscribes the data from another service. On the completion of subscribe event i want to process the data received from server and call the callback method of component who has invoked myFunction. Is that possible to do? something like below:

```
myFunction(callback: function) {
    otherService.getData().subscribe((res: Response) => {
        //do some processing of response
        caller.callback(processed_response)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate Fals' question based on your comment (as you haven't gotten an updated answer).

You can use `.map` instead. You have probably mapped the response once earlier, but you can map several times.

```
 myFunction() : Observable<any>{
    return otherService.getData()
      .map(res => {
         return ... // your processing
      })
}
```

and then `.subscribe`:

```
myFunction.subscribe(data => {
   //do whatever you like
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be more convenient return the `Observable` and then subscribe from the caller.

```
myFunction() : Observable<any>{
    return otherService.getData();
}
```

**At the caller:**

```
myFunction.subscribe((res: Response) => {
        //use the response
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. it would work but if i want to do some processing of data before returning then what should i do?